# How to load a ® (the circled "R") from an external table in oracle table?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, globalization

I am using oracle 10g.The character set for DB is as below: NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16 NLS_CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8.

I have ®(the circled "R") symbol coming in a .txt file in one of the fields and when the same file is loaded in a external table, the symbol is converted in a '?'.

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of the External Table?

Comment: The data type for this column is nvarchar2(500 byte).       `CREATE TABLE "APP_XXX_XX_XXXX"( 
"product_name" NVARCHAR2(500 byte)
"XXX_XXX_XXXXX" VARCHAR2(1 byte), 
"XXX_XXX_XXXXX" NUMBER(9), 
"XXX_XXX_XXXXX" NUMBER(4), 
"XXX_XXX_XXXXX" NUMBER(2), 
"XXX_XXX_XXXXX" NUMBER(3)) 
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
DEFAULT DIRECTORY "DIR"
ACCESS PARAMETERS
( RECORDS DELIMITED BY '~^'
CHARACTERSET 'AL32UTF8'
LOGFILE APP_XXX_XX_XXXX_%A_%P.LOG'
BADFILE 'APP_XXX_XX_XXXX_%A_%P.BAD'
DISCARDFILE 'APP_XXX_XX_XXXX_%A_%P.DSC'
LOCATION
( 'FILE1.TXT')
)
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED`

Comment: User NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR2 and use CHAR instead of byte e.g: `VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)` becomes `NVARCHAR2(1 CHAR)`

Comment: I tried using the follwing definition but still the same problem exists:- `CREATE TABLE @@@@ ( PRD_TITLE NVARCHAR2(400) ) ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY PROD_EXT_TAB ACCESS PARAMETERS ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY '~^' CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8 LOGFILE ext_log:'@@@@.log' BADFILE ext_log:'@@@@.bad' DISCARDFILE ext_log:'@@@@.dsc' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '_^' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS ( prd_title ) ) LOCATION (PROD_EXT_TAB:'@@@@.txt') ) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED NOPARALLEL`

Answer (score 0):

Where do you see the ® being converted to a question mark? It may be a problem in the encoding of what you're using to view the table rather than the table itself. I'd also check what you're using to load the database. UTF8 should support the character.

Comment: I am seeing the ? in Toad.It's not the problem with encoding as i have alraedy set the enocding of the toad to UTF-8 and .txt is also encoded in utf-8. I am using external table to read the .txt file with the ® symbol.Now when i see it through a external table I get a ? in table.